# Como puedo recoger dos o más variables por el data de AJAX? Combo Box

Tags: php, sql, ajax, pdo, crud

Tengo un `combo box` que necesito que recoja dos o más variables para que se de el caso de su funcionamiento, es decir,

tengo esta función:

```
function change_documento1()
        {
            var acro_proyecto = $("#acro_proyecto").val();
            var compania1 = $("#compania1").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "numdocumento.php",
                data: "acro_proyecto=" + acro_proyecto + "compania1=" + compania1,
                cache: false,
                success: function (response)
                {
                    $("#num_documento").html(response);
                }
            });

        }
```

y recibe los datos en este otor php:

```
//Este es el archivo que da acceso a la configuración del combobox 
include('dbConfig.php');

$acro_proyecto = $_POST['acro_proyecto'];
$compania1 = $_POST['compania1'];

$sql= "select MAX(num_documento) from documento where proyecto='$acro_proyecto and ·$compania1'";
$query = $db->query($sql);

echo '<option value="">Selecciona</option>';

while($res = $query->fetch_assoc())
{
    $prueba = $res['MAX(num_documento)']+1;
    echo '<option value="'.$prueba.'">'.$prueba.'</option>';    
}
```

Si a este le quito las opciones de `compania1`funciona perfectamente pero digo que al añadirle la segunda opción no se lo indexo bien, y necesito que la menos funcione con dos o más si es posible.

El problema creo que viene por la select ahora:

```
 $sql= "select MAX(num_documento) from documento where proyecto='$acro_proyecto' and '$compania1'";
```

Esta select en phpmyadmin muestra lo que quiero pero en el **php** no, siempre muestra uno pero si la dejo

```
$sql= "select MAX(num_documento) from documento where proyecto='$acro_proyecto'";
```

funciona a la perfección

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si tu objetivo es enviar esos datos al servidor mediante una peticion post se hace de la siguiente forma:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "numdocumento.php",
            data: {
                 acro_proyecto: acro_proyecto, 
                 compania1: compania1
             },
            cache: false,
            success: function (response)
            {
                $("#num_documento").html(response);
            }
        });
```

Comment: no funciona bien me deberia de sacar un 3 de la select y me saca 1

Comment: revisa la consulta y el response , yo que tu le colocaría un alias al MAX

Comment: lo de response no se como funciona ya que de ajax no se manejarlo unicamente vi un ejemplo lo adapte a mi codigo para que funcionara

Comment: $prueba = $res['MAX(num_documento)']+1;----- esta linea es un poco rara , existe un recurso en sql que se llama alias que te permite ponerle un nombre a los resultados para que luego puedas llamarlos facilmente

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp  -- te dejo un enlace a una explicacion

Comment: lo que le hago en esa línea es, que al resultado que de de la función MAX le sume uno, lo raro es que si yo lo dejo con una unica variable funciona perfectamente me muestra el 3 en vez del 1 como resultado

Comment: haz un console.log de response para que te muestre correctamente que te devuelve

Comment: voy a ver pero la select en phpmyadmin funciona perfectamente así como la tengo, yo croe que le problema viene por ajax. Como hago el console.log?

Comment: en javascript:  console.log(response) dentro de la función success

Comment: cuando se ejecute esa parte del código te aparecera el objeto response en la consola de desarrollador del navegador

Comment: si lo dejo asi sin compania es decir lo djeo en una sola variable funciona correctamente y le suma +1 y si le meto compania deja de sumar

Comment: y si fuera por: while($res = $query->fetch_assoc()) que el fetch estuviera mal para recoger datos y fuera all o algo asi

Comment: la sentencia sql estaba mal si te fijas $compania1 no le digo a que campo me refiero tenia que a ver puesto antes compania='$compania1' y ya funciona perfectamente. Gracias chicos!